# Using <import> w/ XSD & XML parser error

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd

I don't understand what's going on here.  My little parser program passes my XML & XSD changes and loads stuff fine, from what I can tell, but if I put this stuff out there in our production system it blows up.

I'm just now beginning to use the XSD import statement.  What I've done if taken out some user-defined types and put them into a XSD all their own.

Here are some typical errors

Error at file "/home/dfcuser/dataElementsTrans.xsd", line=7, column=37, XML element=, Imported schema 'DFCTypes.xsd' has a different targetNameSpace 'http://www.quikq.com/xsd/dataElementsTrans' from what's declared 'http://www.quikq.com/DFCTypes'

Error at file "/home/dfcuser/dataElementsTrans.xsd", line=29, column=55, XML element=, Schema Representation Constraint: Namespace 'http://www.quikq.com/DFCTypes' is referenced without  declaration

Here is the preamble of the example documents:

```
    DFCTypes.xsd
    ------------
    <xs:schema
        targetNamespace="http://www.quikq.com/DFCTypes" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

    dataElementsTrans.xsd
    ---------------------
    <xs:schema 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:dfct="http://www.quikq.com/DFCTypes" 
        targetNamespace="http://www.quikq.com/xsd/dataElementsTrans" 
        xmlns="http://www.quikq.com/xsd/dataElementsTrans"
        elementFormDefault="qualified" >

        <xs:import schemaLocation="DFCTypes.xsd" namespace="http://www.quikq.com/DFCTypes" />

    XML
    ---
    <dataElementsTrans 
        xmlns="http://www.quikq.com/xsd/dataElementsTrans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quikq.com/xsd/dataElementsTrans dataElementsTrans.xsd">
```

My sample parser program and production code must have something turned on differently.  I'm still pretty green on this so I'm scratching my head for a bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The xs:schema elements whose start-tags you show look OK at first glance.  I would not expect them to elicit those error messages.

The error messages you are showing suggest that the copy of DFCTypes.xsd on your production system is declaring its target namespace as `http://www.quikq.com/xsd/dataElementsTrans` and not as `http://www.quikq.com/DFCTypes` -- perhaps a copy/paste error or just an artefact of an earlier stage of the schema?  (You didn't *just* move the user-defined types to their own schema document, you also moved them to a namespace of their own.)  The second error message you cite suggests that he copy of Trans.xsd being processed lacks the namespace declaration `xmlns:dfct="http://www.quikq.com/DFCTypes"` (as does the reference to the `xs:import` element in line 8 as being in line 7).  So my first act, if I were you, would be to ensure that the schema processor on the production server is finding the documents you think it's finding.  (My usual way of doing that is planting syntax errors in the documents I think it should be reading, and seeing if they are flagged.  That may feel a bit harsh for a production server, but if it's failing anyway ...)

Comment: If I put entity resolver code in my sample parser, it explodes like my production programs.  I gotta say I don't know much about using entity resolvers.

Answer (score 0):

If I put entity resolver code in my sample parser, it explodes like my production programs. I gotta say I don't know much about using entity resolvers.

Class definition:

```
    class MyResolver : public EntityResolver {
    private :
        string m_path;

    public :
        MyResolver(string path) { m_path = path; }

        InputSource* resolveEntity(const XMLCh* const publicId, const XMLCh* const systemId)
        {
            CStr2XStr path(m_path);

            if (XMLString::compareString(systemId, path.unicodeForm())) {
                return new LocalFileInputSource(path.unicodeForm());
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    };
```

Actual use:

```
    MyResolver *resolver = new MyResolver("/home/dfcuser/authNotify.xsd");
    parser->setEntityResolver(resolver);
```

I guess the immediate solution is to remove or correct my entity resolver stuff.  I would love to hear some comments!